# Number of join-irreducibles and rank in a finite lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $(L, r)$ be a finite, ranked lattice. Is
$$r(x) = \#\{j \leq x : j \in L \text{ is join-irreducible}\}$$
for all $x \in L$?

This may be a naive question, though my lattice theory is weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could give a very trivial negative answer just by stating that, if $|L|=n$, and we define a rank function such that $r(0)=n+1$, then the formula can't hold (notice that, at least in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)), it's not necessary that $r(0)=0$).

That said, it's reasonable to think that what you have in mind is a rank function $r$ such that $r(0)=0$.
Even in that case, the result doesn't hold, as the following example shows:

[image]

This is a ranked lattice with ranks $0,1,2,3$, but for the top element, $1$, which satisfies $r(1)=3$, we have $4$ join-irreducibles below it.
All other elements satisfy your formula.

---

**Update**

As I noted in a comment below, the $\mathbf M_3$ lattice ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties)) is an even simpler counter-example.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. Of course $r(0) = 0$ is required. After looking around some more I believe the equality holds for distributive lattices, though I didn't immediately find a citation (...or try to prove it...). Does $\leq$ always hold?

Comment: @JSwanson Yes, you can prove the inequality by induction, for the general case, using the fact that in every finite lattice, each element is the join of the join-irreducible elements below it. In the case of a distributive lattice, I believe you are right, that your formula holds, and that the [Birkhoff's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_representation_theorem) should be helpful in proving it; but it might be true in more general settings (modular lattices?).

Comment: Well, actually, not true in modular lattices, as the $\mathbf M_3$ example shows...